# jQuery .filter() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was stuck with .filter() in my code; it was just not working. Although I have found other solution but I still don't know why the filter won't work (and where the filter should work). I searched a lot but didn't really find anything convincing.

Here's what it is:

```
<form id= "qform">
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="1"/> 1 <br />
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="2"/> 2 <br />
</form>
```

**Method 1**

```
element = $('#qform input[type=radio]');
element = $('#qform :radio');
```

**Method 2**

```
element = $('#qform').find('input[type=radio]')
element = $('#qform').find(':radio')
```

**Method 3**

```
element = $('#qform').filter('input[type=radio]');
element = $('#qform').filter(':radio');
```

Can anyone explain why `1)` & `2)` work fine but `3)` doesn't?

Although jQuery docs says 3) should work fine too:
http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/
What am I missing here?

Cheers!

Comment: Because `filter()` and `find()` do two different things.  Read the docs more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

3rd one doesn't work because it already dont have input type in the selection.

if you Provide input in selection than you can filter the type of those like below

```
element = $('#qform input').filter('[type=radio]');
element = $('#qform input').filter(':radio');
```

[Reference for filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)